# how to get clients sync status via API

Tags: client, api, synchronization

I try to use the build in API by bitcoin client and I wonder how to get the sync status via API of a runing client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1) `getblockcount` gives you the most recent block you have [call it n]

2) `getblockhash n` gives you the hash for that block [call it hash]

3) `getblock hash` gives you the block. You can compare the time of that block with the current time, and estimate how many blocks behind you are. It should be approximately `(now - blocktime) / 600` if the times are in seconds.